# How to draw markers of different sizes

Tags: html, leaflet, gis

The following html script draws specified map tiles and markers as planned. But, the size of markers are same. How can I draw the markers with size as specified in items 3 and 4 in the list 'planes'? This way I can differentiate different markers as per certain properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"
/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

<script
    src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
</script>

<script>

var planes = [
    ["7C6B07",-40.99497,174.50808, 5, 5],
    ["7C6B38",-41.30269,173.63696, 10, 10],
    ["7C6CA1",-41.49413,173.5421, 15, 5],
    ["7C6CA2",-40.98585,174.50659, 15, 15],
    ["C81D9D",-40.93163,173.81726, 20, 5],
    ["C82009",-41.5183,174.78081, 20, 10],
    ["C82081",-41.42079,173.5783, 5, 15],
    ["C820AB",-42.08414,173.96632, 5, 9],
    ["C820B6",-41.51285,173.53274, 7, 12]
    ];

    var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.3058, 174.82082], 8);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

    for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]], {iconSize: [planes[i][3], planes[i][4]]})
            .bindPopup(planes[i][0])
            .addTo(map);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning `iconSize` as an option to marker object. This is not the appropriate way.

Actually, you need to create an `icon` object, set the `iconSize` value there, then use this `icon` object in the options of `map` object.

Here is the code snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {

    //create an icon object for each marker
    var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'http://leafletjs.com/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
        iconSize: [planes[i][3], planes[i][4]] //set icon size here
    });

    marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]], {icon: myIcon})// use the above icon object here
        .bindPopup(planes[i][0])
        .addTo(map);
}
```

Even though the icons are not looking good. Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/0pL8v85t/)

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet doesn't seem to allow users to modify a default marker's size. However you can create you own custom ICON and extend the regular marker class, modify its size and other properties.

Check the documentation here:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon